# Pb with mpmovieplayercontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsnotificationcenter

I need your help please: how can I delete this wihte line?

[image]

```
NSString *AppFolderPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString *MoviePath=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"/%@/%@", AppFolderPath,pathVideo];
NSLog(MoviePath);
NSURL *movieURL=[[NSURL fileURLWithPath:MoviePath]retain];
    movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
   [self addSubview:movieController.view];
   [movieController setMovieControlMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit];
   [movieController setShouldAutoplay:YES];
   [movieController setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I have also tried with same code. (Except that, setMovieControlMode: is removed since it was deprecated). But I 'm not getting that kind of line. Pl. try with another video.

Comment: This is correct and should be the accepted and up voted solution.